# Why can't laser printers always reproduce small isolated dots?

Tags: print-production, laser

I'm studying computer graphics, and it's mentioned that laser printers, differently from inkjet printers, can't reproduce very small isolated dots. But I couldn't find an explanation why.
The only understanding I have of how laser printers work is what is shown in the image below.

This is not an important part of what I'm studying, but I'm just curious. So a simple explanation would be enough.

[image]

Comment: What size is "very small" and what is "Isolated"?

Comment: And do you mean the "very small isolated dot" is omitted completely, or is reproduced at a different size (which? Smaller or larger than intended?)

Comment: This image actually presents photocoying. Printer needs a charge inversion phase to snap the color to the exposed places. The difference isn't essential for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Toner particles allways stick into a little larger area than the photo-exposed one. That's because the electric tractive force can be strong enough to hold the particles, even if it comes a little from aside.